# How can I create a new database with schema within a stored procedure?

Tags: database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to write a TSQL stored procedure that creates a database with a specified name, and pre-populates it with some schema.

So I use lots of EXEC statements:

```
EXEC('CREATE TABLE ' + @dbName + '.dbo.MyTable (...)');
```

etc, along with some `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE FUNCTION` etc. However, the problem comes from when I want to create a type, as CREATE TYPE statements can't have the database specified, and you can't have `USE @dbName` within the stored procedure.

How can I create a type in another database in a stored procedure?

Comment: Why do you want to create a database and schema inside a stored proc??? That seems a bit odd - typically, DML statements should *not* be executed from within stored proc - you execute those once to set up your environment, and then be done with it..

Comment: I want to create an arbitary number of databases depending on the input for our application (one database per customer)

Comment: Create the db back it up, then restore it with a new logical name and file name each time you want to add one.

Comment: I would personally find another way to provision databases and their schema - something like a tool that generates (and possibly executes) the necessary T-SQL scripts - but I would not do this inside a stored procedure...

Answer (score 8):

There are certain commands that can't use used as [ssarabando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215576/ssarabando) suggests, among them is CREATE SCHEMA, which throws [Msg 111](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-111-create-function.aspx) when used in with that technique.

The work around is to nest dynamic SQL blocks as follows:

```
exec('use tempdb; exec sp_executesql N''create schema test'' ')
```

The outer block does nothing except change the database, so that the inner block has the correct context when it is executed.

Notice that the inner parameter to sp_executesql needs two single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at [`sp_addtype`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189784.aspx) instead. You can execute this in the database you want.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use this, for example:

```
EXEC('use ' + @dbName + ';create type somename from int not null;')
```

That'll select the correct database before creating the type.